# How to get <body> in React JS without DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm rebuilding a project in React JS which i did in Vanilla JS, i came across to add, remove classes from `<body>` tag, i am also doing something when screen resizes.
I did this, this is a related piece of code, there's actually bunch of code:

```
...
document.body.onclick = (e) => {
 const { lengua } = e.target.dataset
 setLenguaOpen(lengua ? true : false) // if the target i or you clicked has data-lengua attr (a button has), a dropdown shows up 
 switchTheme                                  // in another component i'm toggle 'switchTheme' (it is boolean), and here what i'm doing depending on it
  ? document.body.classList.add('dark-theme') // in my css, i'm changing values of variables i defined for colors and background-colors if body.dark-theme
  : document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme')
}

window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
 if (e.target.innerWidth >= 850) {
  document.body.classList.remove('menu-open')
 }
})
...
<FaBars onClick={() => document.body.classList.toggle('menu-open')}/> // a menu is located on 0 top: -60px when screen size < 850, i'm transforming body to y:60px to slide down the menu
```

It's working fine, but i think DOM Manipulation is preferably not used by most developers in React. I could do it differently to achieve what i wanted, but now i'm curios to learn how good React developers do what is done by DOM M..., especially the above example. If you have a better approach, i would love to hear it.

If you wanna see what exactly i'm talking, see that project: axelreid-store.netlify.app.
The code i shown is related to header section (languages dropdown, theme switcher, and menu toggle)

I'm sorry if this is a weird question!

Thanks!

Comment: You need to avoid DOM Manipulation for any element within your react root. Outside that react can't actually modify anything directly. You can add a div inside your root that covers the entire page, or just edit the document element directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding direct DOM manipulation when working with React is a good general principle, however there are quite a few cases when it is the best or only approach for solving a problem.

Accessing elements above the React application's top level element **requires** direct DOM manipulation. This also — definitely — is not going to clash with React's own DOM updating methods because they only affect elements inside the application.